# Running Python file from Django views

Tags: python, django, view

I understand this question has been asked before but the methods adviced don't work for me.
This is what I want to do from my Django view:

```
sudo python mypythonscript.py arg1 arg2 > mypythonscript.log
```

If I execute this from command line it works like a charm but can't get it to work through django views.
I have tried using os.system(command) and subprocess.call(command, shell=True) but they don't work.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This is my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
import subprocess

def li_view(request):
if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            message = "This is an XHR GET request"
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            message = "This is an XHR POST request"
            print request.POST
    else:
        message = "No XHR"
    num_instances = request.POST['num_instances']
    ami_id = "ami-ff02058b"
    command = "sudo python /home/bitnami/launch_instances.py 1 " + num_instances + " " + ami_id + " > /home/bitnami/launcinstances.log"
    subprocess.call(commad, shell=True)
    return HttpResponse("something creative will go here later")
```

The whole story is that I have a form on my website and I want to pass the contents of that form as arguements to my launch_instances.py script.
When I press the submit button in my form it posts to /luanch_instances/ which 'redirects' to this view.
Executing the code as it is will do nothing, it'll simply just show me "something creating will go here later" on a new page.
If I was to how ever use

```
suprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
```

This is what I get:

```
Command 'sudo python /home/bitnami/launch_instances.py 1 ami-ff02058b > /home/bitnami/launchinstances.log' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Comment: You need to tell us why didn't it work. Show your code and output.

Comment: Also what are you trying to accomplish by doing this in a python view? It is generally advisable to use a task queue such as Celery to perform this sorts of things as it doesn't tie up your web server.

Comment: @VladimirVolodin i've added the output and code now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're trying to run python script, you may simply import code from launch_instances.py into your view, redirect output to /home/bitnami/launcinstances.log (about redirecting stdout to file in python: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)). But there's still problem with root privileges - one option is to change permissions of: resources needed for calling code from launch_instances.py; your log file; to allow your django process to execute that, second option (not recommended) is to run django app as root.

Comment: I don't know why executing: sudo python mypythonscript.py arg1 arg2 > mypythonscript.log needs root permissions. Assume that mypythonscript.py is not owned by owner of django process, then you may simply do chmod a+rx mypythonscript.pl

Comment: But remember that doing chmod a+rx may break security.

Comment: its alright i didn't need to use chmod a+rx in the end. Simply importing the script did the job :) cheers

Answer (score 3):

Most likely it has something to do with permissions. Try examining stderr and stdout of your command execution. I'm using this code to debug my shell commands:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output,error = process.communicate(input=pipe)
```

Comment: assuming that by input=pipe you meant input=subprocess.PIPE, I get the followng error: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'